# How to get name of an enumeration in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, oop, enums

I define an enumerated type in MATLAB

```
classdef(Enumeration) Color < Simulink.IntEnumType
  enumeration
    RED(0),
    GREEN(1),
    BLUE(2),
  end
end
```

I can assign it:

```
>> x = Color.RED    
x = 
    RED
```

I can display it like this:

```
>> disp(x)
    RED
```

or like this

```
>> x.display()
x =
    RED
```

How can I get access to that name ("RED") as a string?

In other words I'm lookin for something like:

```
s = x.toString()
```

or

```
s = tostring(x)
```

both of which do not work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use:

```
» str = char(Color.RED)
str =
RED
» class(str)
ans =
char
```

You can even override the default behaviour:

```
classdef(Enumeration) Color < int32
 enumeration
  RED(0)
  GREEN(1)
  BLUE(2)
 end

 methods
  function s = char(obj)
   s = ['Color ' num2str(obj)];
   %# or use a switch statement..
  end

  function disp(obj)
   disp( char(obj) )
  end
 end
end
```

and now:

```
» char(Color.BLUE)
ans =
Color 2
```

Comment: note: since I dont have simulink, I tested the above using the definition: `classdef(Enumeration) Color < int32`

Comment: Did you test what `str` actually was? I can't test it right now, but I think this might just convert the *integer representation* of the enumerated type to a `char` (i.e. `char(0)`).

Comment: @gnovice: it is returning `"RED"` as expected

Answer (score 0):

A different approach, generic, in your calling entitiy:

```
strtrim(matlab.unittest.diagnostics.ConstraintDiagnostic.getDisplayableString(Color.BLUE))
```

This way you can save the class specific implementation of disp() and/or char().